# Why image shown in UITabBar, on selected item, not properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an UITabBar and set 2 images for a tab(active item, deactive item). On deactive item tab icon shown properly as:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzeCj.jpg)

but when those item is active, icon not shown properly:

[Image here](http://imgur.com/JW1umwd)

Can anyone help me to fix it? I was that it will colour just borders of the icon, not entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check this screenshot: At right side of the screen see 'Rendered as' text and select drop down and use Original image. Your problem would be solved. Hope this helps..

[image]

Comment: great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UIImageRenderingMode for that.

```
        UIImage *imgNormal=[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"];
        imgNormal=[imgNormal imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

        UIImage *imgSelected=[UIImage imageNamed:@"active.png"];
        imgSelected=[imgSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        tabBarItem.image = imgNormal; 
        tabBarItem.selectedImage = imgSelected;
```

Hope it helps :).