# Gray square instead of an image in the tab bar. I use storyboard

Tags: ios, swift2, storyboard

I uploaded a picture in the project, have it in the inspector, but only bar button draws a gray square. In other examples, nothing further is required. What to do?
[image]

Comment: does your image have any alpha or is it fully colored image ?

Comment: Are you sure that Text.png is attached to project?

Comment: PNG RGB+Alfa, yes, attached

Comment: Useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236168/why-image-shown-in-uitabbar-on-selected-item-not-properly/37237505?noredirect=1#comment62012156_37237505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITabBarItems' image property automatically sets the render mode of images to template. If you want to use a full color image as a tabbar item image you should explicitly set the render mode of the image to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`. You can set this in a .xcassets folder by selecting the image, opening the right pane, and setting render as "Original Image". Right now the tabbar is only looking at the alpha value of the image and tinting it gray. For more information you should look at the [UIKit User Interface Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html)

Comment: Many thanks, beowulf!  I would have had to seek solutions)